# In Memory OleDbConnection to Excel File

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005, excel

I would like to open an OleDbConnection to an Excel file that's in memory as a 
FileStream. Does anyone know if this is possible and how to accomplish it?

Big picture I would like to pass the file bytes into a .NET CLR Stored Procedure and extract the data. Perhaps there's a better way to do this that I've not considered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it that you want to pass tabular data to the stored procedure?

Comment: Ideally, I would just pass the Excel file to the .NET SP as a Blob or byte[]. Inside the SP I will crack it open and process the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VSTO solution JP offers is definitely viable. However, if you really want to use OleDb and some SQL, take a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686) artcile: it's a MS knowledge base article that describes how to import data from excel into SQLSever using OleDb.

Comment: Esteban, excellent article. However, of all the method mentioned appear to rely on the Excel file being persisted to disk. Any idea how these techniques could be utilized to attach to an in-memory Excel file or Blob column?

Thanks.

Comment: @Steve: I don't know, but I don't think so.

Comment: @EstebanAraya I ask a similar question about but about Access here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475968/read-access-file-accdb-from-stream would you please check it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which Im lookin for an answer as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) to open a file from a byte array in memory or from any stream with SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbookSet().Workbooks.OpenFromMemory(byte[]) / OpenFromStream(System.IO.Stream).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data using [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d(VS.80).aspx).  It has an [object model for Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel(VS.80).aspx).  Then pass what you want to the proc.  I think that would be better than trying to have the CLR stored proc decipher an Excel file stream.

Comment: I ask a similar question about but about Access here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475968/read-access-file-accdb-from-stream would you please check it.