# Can I read Excel files using the OleDbConnection Excel ACE Driver from a non-seekable System.IO.Stream rather than a file?

Tags: c#, windows, excel, stream, oledbconnection

There's a similar question here [In Memory OleDbConnection to Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908712/in-memory-oledbconnection-to-excel-file) but, this question was answered by avoiding it completely by doing it another way.

Here's some example code which uses an `OleDbConnection` to access an Excel file from disk:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String filePathToExcelFile = "c:\\excelfile.xls";
    Boolean hasHeaders = true;

    String connectionString = String.Format(
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};" +
        "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR={1};IMEX=2\"",
        filePathToExcelFile, hasHeaders ? "Yes" : "No");

    using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", 
        conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader datareader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while(datareader.Read())
        {
            Object[] values = new object[datareader.FieldCount];
            datareader.GetValues(values);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", values));
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to pull the Excel file from a NON-SEEKABLE `System.IO.Stream`, not a persistent file on the disk.

The question breaks down into two parts, a) Can I "point" the OleDbConnection to a System.IO.Stream? b) If so can that be a forward only stream rather than a seekable one?

FYI: if you want to run this code snippet you'll need to install the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255). And if you install the 64 bit one you'll need to target the project to be x64 and vice versa.

Comment: I highly doubt you'd be able to do this under the non-seekable constraint. Excel files, whether the convuluted binary of .xls (as you have shown) or the organized XML of .xlsx [(OOXML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML), have information in decidedly non-serial format. I.e. it is not possible to process an Excel file purely sequentially.

Comment: Check the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908712/in-memory-oledbconnection-to-excel-file

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it helps: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

also sample code:

```
string fileName = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\SUPPLIERDECISIONKEYLIST.xlsx";
using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
{
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
pck.Load(stream);
}
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[SheetNo];
```